# Twilio Certificate Sandbox attribute mismatch

Tags: twilio, react-native-ios

I am trying to add push credentials on twilio using a productions certificate (Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)), however when I try to save the push credentials while having the SandBox checkbox unchecked I get an error stating **Certificate Sandbox attribute mismatch** , please help thank you!

Comment: Did you get this sorted?

Comment: Yes I think it was related to not having the right certificate